# Laravel PHP test hash of downloaded file

Tags: php, download, zip, phpunit, laravel-9

In my web application I've written functionality to create an Excel file, encrypt it in a zip file and then download it. This works fine. However, I'm struggling to write a test for it. I'd like write a test that downloads the encrypted zip file and then checks the hash of this file against an expected hash i.e. to test that the file contents are as expected. This is my function:

```
public function downloadPost(DataExportRequest $dataExportRequest)
{
    $currentLocalStore = Auth::user()->currentLocalStore;
    $allCustomers = Customer::whereIn('address_id', $currentLocalStore->addresses())->get();

    $customerData = [];
    foreach ($allCustomers as $customer)
    {
        $entry = $customer->exportArray();
        array_push($customerData, $entry);
    }

    $export = new CustomerExport($customerData);

    Excel::store($export, 'customer data.xlsx');

    $zip_file = 'customer data as zip.zip';
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($zip_file, \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
    $excelFile = 'customer data.xlsx';
    $zip->addFile(storage_path('app/' . 'customer data.xlsx'), $excelFile);
    $zip->setEncryptionName($excelFile, ZipArchive::EM_AES_256, dataExportRequest['password']);

    $zip->close();

    return response()->download($zip_file);
```

}

Here's my test so far (which passes):

```
public function testFileDownloadsWithCorrectHeaders(): void
{
    Storage::fake('public');
    $this->be(User::find(1));
    Auth::user()->setCurrentLocalStore(1);
    $response = $this->followingRedirects()->post('/data-export', []);

    $this->assertEquals($response->getStatusCode(), 200);
}
```

The test doesn't actually download a file which is I suppose what you'd expect from a test. So how can I expand the test to test the hash of the downloaded file is as expected? Many thanks in advance for your help.

I'm running Laravel 9.52.10, PHP 8.2.0.

Comment: First of all, you don't need to zip the file, xlsx is already a zip archive. Then, you cannot validate contents of the file without actually downloading (getting a response body). To check if file recieved is the same that was sent, you could add a HTTP header like 'X-Download-MD5-Hashsum: ...' with a md5 (or any other hashing algo) hash of the contents, calculate the hash for incoming data in your test and compare this hash with that header value.

Comment: Many thanks Jarad that's a huge help.